# Does python have a sorted list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

By which I mean a structure with:

- O(log n) complexity for `x.push()` operations
- O(log n) complexity to find an element
- O(n) complexity to compute `list(x)` which will be sorted

I also had a related question about performance of `list(...).insert(...)` which is now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110332/performance-of-list-insert).

Comment: `memcpy` is still a *O(n)* operation. I am not sure how Python implements lists *exactly*, but my bet would be that they are stored in contiguous memory (certainly not as a linked list). If that is indeed so, the insertion using `bisect` which you demonstrate will have complexity *O(n)*.

Comment: Sadly not out the box. But Grant Jenk's [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) library is excellent. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22616929/284795

Comment: In many cases you can predict maximum number of elements, in which case you can preallocate memory once and never need memcpy afterwards.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The standard Python list is not sorted in any form. The standard [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module can be used to append in O(log n) to an existing list and remove the smallest one in O(log n), but isn't a sorted list in your definition.

There are various implementations of balanced trees for Python that meet your requirements, e.g. [rbtree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rbtree/), [RBTree](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/rbtree.html), or [pyavl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyavl/).

Comment: +1 for rbtree, it works very well (but contains native code; not pure python, not so easy to deploy perhaps)

Comment: [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) is pure-Python and fast-as-C (like rbtree) with a performance comparison.

Comment: "isn't a sorted list in your definition." How so?

Comment: heapq only allows to find the smallest element; the OP was asking for a structure that can find any element in O(log n), which heaps are not.

Answer (score 119):

Is there a particular reason for your big-O requirements? Or do you just want it to be fast? The [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) module is pure-Python and fast (as in fast-as-C implementations like blist and rbtree).

The [performance comparison](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) shows it benchmarks faster or on par with blist's sorted list type. Note also that rbtree, RBTree, and PyAVL provide sorted dict and set types but don't have a sorted list type.

If performance is a requirement, always remember to benchmark. A module that substantiates the claim of being fast with Big-O notation should be suspect until it also shows benchmark comparisons.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the Python sortedcontainers module.

---

Installation:

```
pip install sortedcontainers
```

Usage:

```
>>> from sortedcontainers import SortedList
>>> l = SortedList()
>>> l.update([0, 4, 1, 3, 2])
>>> l.index(3)
3
>>> l.add(5)
>>> l[-1]
5
```

Comment: Indeed I compared sortedcontainers against bisect: `0.0845024989976` for SortedList.add() vs `0.596589182518` for bisect.insort(), thus a difference of 7x in speed! And I expect the speed gap to increase with the list length since sortedcontainers insertion sort works in O(log n) while bisect.insort() in O(n).

Comment: @gaborous because bisect still uses a list, so the insertion remains `O(n)`

Comment: Just a 5 cents: If one needs to sort objects from custom class, use SortedList's subclass, called SortedKeyList.

Comment: Presumably, the reason for the big-O requirements is specifically that they imply either a balanced binary tree representation or equivalent.

Answer (score 39):

Though I have still never checked the "big O" speeds of basic Python list operations, 
the `bisect` standard module is probably also worth mentioning in this context:

```
import bisect
L = [0, 100]

bisect.insort(L, 50)
bisect.insort(L, 20)
bisect.insort(L, 21)

print L
## [0, 20, 21, 50, 100]

i = bisect.bisect(L, 20)
print L[i-1], L[i]
## 20, 21
```

PS. Ah, sorry, `bisect` is mentioned in the referenced question. Still, I think it won't be much harm if this information will be here )

PPS. And [CPython lists are actually arrays](http://jjinux.blogspot.com/2008/03/pycon-core-python-containers-under-hood.html) (not, say, skiplists or etc) . Well, I guess they have to be something simple, but as for me, the name is a little bit misleading.

---

So, if I am not mistaken, the bisect/list speeds would probably be:

- for a push(): O(n) for the worst case ;
- for a search: if we consider the speed of array indexing to be O(1), search should be an O(log(n)) operation ;
- for the list creation: O(n) should be the speed of the list copying, otherwise it's O(1) for the same list )

**Upd.** Following a discussion in the comments, let me link here these SO questions: [How is Python's List Implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented) and [What is the runtime complexity of python list functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005590/what-is-the-runtime-complexity-of-python-list-functions)

Comment: push() should be in O(log n) since the list is already sorted.

Comment: may be I should have said ["for an insert op"](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort_left). anyway, that was about a year ago so now I can easily mix things up or miss something

Comment: You can always insert a value into a sorted list in O(log n), see binary search. push() is defined as an insert operation.

Comment: True. But while _finding_ the insert location would indeed take O(log n) ops, the actual insert (i.e. adding the element to the data structure) probably depends on that structure (think inserting an element in a sorted array). And as [Python lists are actually arrays](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/), this may take O(n). Due to the size limit for the comments, I will link two related SO questions from the text of the answer (see above).

Comment: Good argument. I wasn't aware list where handled as arrays in Python.

Comment: It is a bit of a misnomer indeed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's about an algorithm rather than a data structure, and it just describes maintaining an ordinary list in sorted order - in a way that doesn't meet the performance requirements that would be met by a balanced binary tree or similar. (Of course, it is O(1) rather than O(lg N) for *indexing*; there is still contiguous storage, whereas the tree-based approach needs to do work comparable to a search in order to index.)

Answer (score 5):

Though it does not (yet) provide a custom search function, the [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html) module may suit your needs. It implements a heap queue using a regular list. You'd have to write your own efficient membership test that makes use of the queue's internal structure (that can be done in *O(log n)*, I'd say...). There is one downside: extracting a sorted list has complexity *O(n log n)*.

Comment: It's nice but hard to bisect.

Comment: How can there be an O(log n) membership test in a heap? If you are looking for value x, you can stop looking down a branch if you find something larger than x, but for a random value of x it is 50% likely to be at a leaf, and you probably can't prune much.

Answer (score 5):

```
import bisect

class sortedlist(list):
    '''just a list but with an insort (insert into sorted position)'''
    def insort(self, x):
        bisect.insort(self, x)
```

Comment: the implied insert() in bisect.insort() is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

An [AVL Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) coupled with in-order traversal will solve this problem in the required time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be hard to implement your own sortlist on Python. Below is a proof of concept:

```
import bisect

class sortlist:
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = list
        self.sort()
    def sort(self):
        l = []
        for i in range(len(self.list)):
            bisect.insort(l, self.list[i])
        self.list = l
        self.len = i
    def insert(self, value):
        bisect.insort(self.list, value)
        self.len += 1
    def show(self):
        print self.list
    def search(self,value):
        left = bisect.bisect_left(self.list, value)
        if abs(self.list[min([left,self.len-1])] - value) >= abs(self.list[left-1] - value):
            return self.list[left-1]
        else:
            return self.list[left]

list = [101, 3, 10, 14, 23, 86, 44, 45, 45, 50, 66, 95, 17, 77, 79, 84, 85, 91, 73]
slist = sortlist(list)
slist.show()
slist.insert(99)
slist.show()
print slist.search(100000000)
print slist.search(0)
print slist.search(56.7)
```

========= Results ============

[3, 10, 14, 17, 23, 44, 45, 45, 50, 66, 73, 77, 79, 84, 85, 86, 91, 95, 101]

[3, 10, 14, 17, 23, 44, 45, 45, 50, 66, 73, 77, 79, 84, 85, 86, 91, 95, 99, 101]

101

3

50

Comment: This is still based on `insort`, which has O(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard library `bisect` module or the third-party `sortedcontainers` package. Alternately, the `heapq` module solves the problem by implementing a heap queue.

Answer (score -2):

Interesting case: if your list `L` is already sorted (for example because you appended them in a sorted order), you can benefit from a fast **lookup** in O(log n) with a standard Python list with this method:

```
import bisect
def in_sorted_list(elem, sorted_list):
    i = bisect.bisect_left(sorted_list, elem)
    return i != len(sorted_list) and sorted_list[i] == elem
L = ["aaa", "bcd", "hello", "world", "zzz"]
print(in_sorted_list("hellu", L))       # False
```

More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281681).

Comment: This information was already covered repeatedly by existing answers.