# Performance of list(...).insert(...)

Tags: python, architecture, memory, list, memcpy

I thought about the following question about computer's architecture. Suppose I do in Python

```
from bisect import bisect
index = bisect(x, a)      # O(log n)  (also, shouldn't it be a standard list function?)
x.insert(index, a)        # O(1) + memcpy()
```

which takes `log n`, plus, if I correctly understand it, a memory copy operation for `x[index:]`. Now I read recently that the bottleneck is usually in the communication between processor and the memory so the memory copy *could* be done by RAM quite fast. Is it how that works?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python is a language. [Multiple implementations exist](https://www.python.org/download/alternatives/), and they *may* have different implementations for lists. So, without looking at the code of an actual implementation, you cannot know for sure how lists are implemented and how they behave under certain circumstances.

My bet would be that the references to the objects in a list are stored in contiguous memory (certainly not as a linked list...). If that is indeed so, then insertion using `x.insert` will cause all elements behind the inserted element to be moved. This may be done efficiently by the hardware, but the complexity would still be *O(n)*.

For small lists the `bisect` operation may take more time than `x.insert`, even though the former is *O(log n)* while the latter is *O(n)*. For long lists, however, I'd hazard a guess that `x.insert` is the bottleneck. In such cases you must consider using a different data structure.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying that memcpy() is O(1) -- I know it's O(n), but the  constant can be small - and I'm not sure if it's really optimized by memory. But if it is optimized to be, say, 1000 times faster than you'd think naively, that's probably something worth knowing.

Comment: In some cases, there might not be any space left in the list, so the whole list has to be copied after new free memory is allocated instead of only a memmove/memcpy.

Comment: The answer is valid, but the first paragraph is not necessarily true in general. A language may specify which operations are designed to be efficient under certain circumstances, so that even without looking at the source code of a particular implementation, you can be confident of certain performance properties of those operations, assuming the implementation is conformant.

Answer (score 12):

Use the [blist module](http://www.python.org/pypi/blist/) if you need a list with better insert performance.

Answer (score 7):

CPython lists are contiguous arrays. Which one of the O(log n) bisect and O(n) insert dominates your performance profile depends on the size of your list and also the constant factors inside the O(). Particularly, the comparison function invoked by bisect can be something expensive depending on the type of objects in the list.

If you need to hold potentially large mutable sorted sequences then the linear array underlying Pythons list type isn't a good choice. Depending on your requirements heaps, trees or skip-lists might be appropriate.