# How can I search a python dictionary from a user's input that will only match part of the element in my dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a dictionary with a structure like this:

```
{
    'www.site.sx/file1.html' : 'TITLE1 101 Project Caspian', 
    'www.site.sx/file2.html' : 'TITLE2 102 Filter Spencer'
}
```

I want to be able to have the user just type in `title2 102` to match the second entry here so the program can get resources from the associated link. How can I search my dictionary with a wildcard match using the user's inputted value?

---

Example:

The user types in

```
title1 101
```

or perhaps

```
Title1 101
```

Now, how can I use this / parse this to get a match in the dictionary?

---

*n.b.* - Case sensitivity matters...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605017/python-hash-table-for-fuzzy-matching. Also, are you trying to match on key or value?

Comment: Should that be `Title1 101` for the second reference example?

Comment: @user3404787, your dictionary example seems to have the user's input matching with the values rather than the keys of your dictionary.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor, yes. Changing it now.

Comment: If case sensitivity matters, does this mean you want to return no results if the user enters something with the wrong case?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off restructuring your data, if possible:

```
DATA = {
    'title1 101': ('www.site.sx/file1.html', 'Project Caspian'), 
    'title2 102': ('www.site.sx/file2.html', 'Filter Spencer'),
}
```

Then it's a simple case of doing:

```
user_input = 'Title1 101'
link, title = DATA[user_input]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `in` to check if a substring is present in your full text:

```
[k for k in mydict if userInput.lower() in mydict[k].lower()]
```

This returns all the url's which have the matching text (certainly, there can be several of them).

Comment: Is searches are going to be O(n), then there's no point in using a dictionary.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik It will be the case anyway if text comparison is needed.

Comment: yes, you're right. initially the question was about searching the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
In [41]: d = {
   ....: 'www.site.sx/file1.html' : 'title1 101 Project Caspian',
   ....: 'www.site.sx/file2.html' : 'title2 102 Filter Spencer'
   ....: }

In [43]: d.values()
Out[43]: ['title1 101 Project Caspian', 'title2 102 Filter Spencer']

In [48]: d.keys()
Out[48]: ['www.site.sx/file1.html', 'www.site.sx/file2.html']
```

You can create a function

```
In [45]: def index1(vals, item):
   ....:     for i, v in enumerate(vals):
   ....:         if item in v: return i
   ....:     return -1
```

such that

```
In [46]: index1(d.values(), 'temp')
Out[46]: -1

In [47]: index1(d.values(), 'title2')
Out[47]: 1
```

Then, you can always do:

```
In [50]: d.keys()[index1(d.values(), 'title2')]
Out[50]: 'www.site.sx/file2.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting your statement about case sensitivity as you want it to work even if the user does not type in the correct case.

One possible solution, which runs in `O(log(n))` but has an `O(n log n)` preprocessing step, is to put the keys into a sorted list and do a binary search to find the correct key, followed by the key lookup.

Your dictionary would look like this:

```
{
    'TITLE1 101 Project Caspian' : 'www.site.sx/file1.html', 
    'TITLE2 102 Filter Spencer' : 'www.site.sx/file2.html',
}
```

You would then have a sorted list like this:

```
['TITLE1 101 Project Caspian', 'TITLE2 102 Filter Spencer']
```

As a preprocessing step, you would make everything lowercase, to deal with the case issue.
When an input `x` came in from the user, you would

1. Make it lowercase.
2. Do a binary search through your list.
3. Check if the query is a prefix of the element that the binary search returned.
4. If it is, then you would do the lookup in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {"Vendor": ("Cisco", "Juniper", "HP"), "Model": "2600", "RAM": "128", "IOS": "12.4", "Ports": "4"}
search = raw_input("What are you looking for : ")
looking = (dict1[search])
print looking
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!