# Is there a way to never build an unbalanced tree?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have written some python code that will take an unbalanced binary tree and balance it, however this has proven to take a long time with very large trees so I'm looking for an easier way...

I was just wondering if it is possible to maintain the trees balance WHILE its being built, so I don't have to waste resources balancing trees after they've already been built.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for AVL tree or `B/B+`

Comment: Search for AVL  or Red-Black trees.

Comment: Yes, AVL/red-black trees are what you're looking for. Unfortunately, there seems to be [no balanced binary tree in the Python standard library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298165/pythons-standard-library-is-there-a-module-for-balanced-binary-tree), so you either need to find a third-party module or code your own.

Comment: Ah yes, AVL trees are exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: try [bintrees](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees), it's a good implementation of various tree algorithms.