# Is there a Python equivalent for C++ "multiset<int>"?

Tags: c++, python, set, multiset

I am porting some C++ code to Python and one of the data structures is a multiset, but I am not sure how to model this in Python.

Let `ms` be the C++ `multiset<int>`

How `ms` is used (posting some examples)

```
multiset<int>::iterator it = ms.find(x)
ms.erase(it)

ms.insert(x)
ms.end()
ms.lower_bound(x)
ms.clear()
```

Comment: You may check `Counter` class in python: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Are there equivalents for the functions/methods I've listed?

Comment: `Counter` is not an equivalent to `std::multiset`.

Comment: Looking through it -- I don't think this has what I need unfortunately

Comment: You don't need exact equivalents for specific functions. 'end' is a C++ way of doing things - it will differ in python.  The C++ is using find, I guess on the ordered set for speed.

Comment: Is there a difference between a multiset and a Python list or set (or dict)? I am just trying to find a way to emulate this.

Comment: Do you need log-time existence check? If not, how about going just with python's list()?

Comment: Well, multiset is ordered, and has logarithmic lookup.

Comment: @MrP Well yes, please study the documentation. Time complexity aside, python's set is what is says - no duplicities allowed.

Comment: So is a multiset just an ordered list with a built-in logarithmic lookup? i.e. a Python list where I can use the bisect module or a binary search function?

Comment: I did Google it and didn't find what I was looking for. If you are just going to respond with "snark," please do not reply in this thread.

Comment: The C++ `multiset` seems to have a richer interface than the Python `Counter`.  Additionally, the C++ `multiset` is ordered, so methods like `lower_bound` don't have any meaning in Python's `Counter`.  Basically, they their use cases overlap somewhat, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: @MrP No I am not used to do that, sorry if you took it this way. It's just that when you google "c++ multiset", the first two results give you just what you were wondering about in your previous post ("So is a multiset just an ordered list with a built-in logarithmic lookup?")

Comment: A sorted list data type fits your criteria. Python has a couple implementations of those on the Python Package Index (PyPI).

Comment: @taocp You should post this as an answer (with a Python 3 link).

Comment: Boost Python can help address your challenges of porting without a Python substitute for multiset in C++.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't. See [Python's standard library - is there a module for balanced binary tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298165/pythons-standard-library-is-there-a-module-for-balanced-binary-tree) for a general discussion of the equivalents of C++ tree containers (`map`, `set`, `multimap`, `multiset`) in Python.

The closest I can think of is to use a dictionary mapping integers to counts (also integers). However this doesn't get you the keys in order, so you can't search using `lower_bound`. An alternative is a to use an ordered list, as suggested by others already, maybe a list of (integer, count) tuples? If you only need to search after you've done all your insertions, you could use the dictionary as a temporary structure for construction, build the list after you've done all the insertions, then use the list for searching.

Comment: Yes, the code does a lot of insertions first, and then searches/removes various items afterwards. Both processes use a lot of lower_bound calls.

Comment: @MrP Do you know why there are `lower_bound` calls during the insertion process? Re `lower_bound` calls during the removal process, if you had a list of `(integer, count)` tuples, you could remove items by decrementing the count, and if a count reached zero, you could leave the item there and clean up sometime later. (Insertions of completely new integers would be more of a problem!)

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple implementations of sorted list data types which would fit your criteria. Two popular choices are [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) and [blist](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/) modules. Each of these modules provides a [SortedList](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) data type which automatically maintains the elements in sorted order and would allow for fast insertion and lower/upper bound lookups. There's a [performance comparison](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) that's helpful too.

The equivalent code using the SortedList type from the SortedContainers module would be:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList
sl = SortedList()

# Start index of `x` values
start = sl.bisect_left(x)

# End index of `x` values
end = sl.bisect_right(x)

# Iterator for those values
iter(sl[start:end])

# Erase an element
del sl[start:end]

# Insert an element
sl.add(x)

# Iterate from lower bound
start = sl.bisect_left(x)
iter(sl[x] for x in range(start, len(sl)))

# Clear elements
sl.clear()
```

All of those operations should work efficiently on a sorted list data type.

Answer (score 4):

You can keep a list ordered using the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) functions. For example `find` will become

```
def index(a, x):
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
        return i
    raise ValueError
```

You will find other equivalents [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists). Instead of checking against `end` you will now get a `ValueError`

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of data-structures which come close.

- python collections:

  - Ordered dict: dict subclass that remembers the order entries were added. [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)
  - Counter: dict subclass for counting hashable objects. [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

    ---
- provided by django framework:

  - A dict with multiple keys with same value: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict)
  - Sorted dict which is deprecated as python collection includes an ordered dict now: [link](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict)

    ---

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need sorting, you can use this as a `multiset<int>` (or `unordered_multiset<int>`):

```
from collections import Counter

def multiset(array):
    return set(Counter(array).items())
```

Comment: You would just use `Counter` directly. Converting the Counter's `items()` to a `set` doesn't make any sense. But in any case this would be an equivalent to `unorderered_multiset`, not to `multiset`.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, There is a model like cpp u can:->
You can use https://pypi.org/project/sortedmultiset/ same as the multiset like cpp
User Guide for this https://github.com/rishiko/sortedmultiset/blob/main/User%20Guide

```
$ pip install orderdmultiset
import sortedmultiset
mset=sortedmultiset.orderdmultiset()--->To create an object of sorted multiset
mset.append(5)#-----> add an element to the multiset
mset.append(4)
print(mset.multiset)#-------->To print the multiset #output [4,5]
mset.erase(4) #---------> True element present and erased #output True
print(mset.multiset)#-------->To print the multiset #output [5]
mset.erase(56)-----------------> False as element not present in multiset #output False.
mset.append(6)
mset.append(3)
print(mset.multiset)#-------->To print the multiset #output [3,5,6]
chq=mset.search(5)#----------> will give a memory address as element present #output 
                              <sortedmultiset.sortedmultiset.TreeNode object at 0x000002C6C69E44F0>
chq=mset.search(678) #-----------> output will be None as element is not present
```

It is an just for a integer numbers i am working on string

Comment: SO is not the place to promote your personal projects.