# Validate word uses letters only from random list

Tags: python, string

I'm building a 'scrabble' game in Python. Basically, the user is given 7 randomly generated letters and these are stored in the list `random_letters`. They then enter a word using those letters - this is a string stored as `player1_word`.

The bit I am stuck on is where I need to validate that the user has entered a valid word - e.g is `player1_word` only using letters from `random_letters`.

```
def is_valid_answer(player_word: str, letters: list) -> bool:
    ...
```

Expected behaviour:

```
>>> random_letters = ["D", "O", "G", "P", "X", "K"]
>>> is_valid_answer("DOG", random_letters)
True
>>> is_valid_answer("CAT", random_letters)
False
```

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: show your approach first

Comment: Is your question: "How can I determine whether a string `word` consists only of characters from a certain list?"

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is from the question.

Comment: I did a rather major rewrite to make the question clearer and more in Python style, please ask if there's anything I changed you're unsure on.

Comment: @gz. Fine, thanks for the edit, much appreciated. I have marked the answer that helped me below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set` operation to do this:

```
if not set(Player1Word) - set(randomLetters):
    print "Valid"
```

`set` is a data structure contains only unique items. The idea is, convert both of them set. And, then subtract `randomLetters` from `Player1Word` to see if `Player1Word` contains something that not in  `randomLetters`. If it doesn't contain, the  `Player1Word` is valid, otherwise not.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, just what I was looking for. Never knew about 'set' before, never come across it. Many thanks ;)

Comment: There is a subtle problem with this answer. For instance, if I am given the letters A,E,O,D,T,W,X and provide the answer WOOD, your code will report my answer as valid when it is not.

Comment: @gz. Indeed it does, good spot. My bad for not testing thoroughly! Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @sf318 was giving others a chance to fix/answer, but have posted a solution now.

Answer (score 0):

```
randomLetters = [ 'a' , 'b' , 'x']

word = input('Enter A word : ')
first_letter = word[0]
if first_letter in randomLetters:
  print('valid')
else:
  print('Not valid')
```

**RESULT**

```
Enter A word :  alex
valid

Enter A word :  devon
Not valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Python [does not have a native multiset type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346905/is-there-a-python-equivalent-for-c-multisetint) so there's not quite a one-liner for this, but [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) helps a little:

```
def is_valid_answer(word, letters):
    letter_counts = collections.Counter(letters)
    for letter in word:
        if not letter_counts[letter]:
            return False
        letter_counts[letter] -= 1
    return True
```

Using `Counter` at least saves you the loop you'd need to populate a plain `dict` with the counts.

Comment: Thanks for posting, will test as soon as I get the chance to :)