# Built-in binary search tree in Python?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, built-in

Are there any **self-balancing binary search tree** (*RED-BLACK*, *AVL* or others) built-in types in Python 2.7 or Python 3.x?

I am looking for something equivalent to Java's [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

If there are no such built-ins, why have they been ommited? Is there a special reason, for not including such tools?

Comment: There are none in the standard library. Why one hasn't been included is impossible to answer. The rest of your question is a request for external resources, which is off-topic.

Comment: Near-dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298165/pythons-standard-library-is-there-a-module-for-balanced-binary-tree

Comment: There's a Heap implementation which is a sort of binary tree. Look for `heapq`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's no special reason, to my knowledge - I'd guess that the reason is that for so many applications the highly-tuned `dict` and `set` implementations (which are hash tables) work well. They're good enough in most cases. There are definitely situations where you need the performance characteristics of balanced binary search trees (like ordered traversal based on key- rather than addition-order), but those are far enough off the beaten path that people are happy with grabbing a third-party package in that case.

I've had a good experience using the [bintrees](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/) package on PyPI. This has implementations of unbalanced, AVL and red-black binary trees, in both pure Python and as extensions written in [Cython](http://cython.org/).

I think the rest of the reason is essentially historical accident. If the person who wrote bintrees lobbied for its inclusion in the stdlib, and was willing to put up with the constraints that imposes on maintenance and releases, it would probably go in. (Although the Cython dependency would cause a problem, I'd guess.)

**Algorithmic complexity:**

For hash tables (like dicts or sets), insertion and lookup are O(1), while for a balanced tree these are O(log(n)). In-order traversal of keys is O(n) in a tree, but to do the same thing with a hash table you need to sort the keys first, so it's O(n*log(n)). When you're picking which kind of data structure to use, you need to think about which operations you're going to be using, and pick the tradeoff that makes the most sense in your application.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I'm guessing that probably `dict` and `set` are actually binary search trees, or maybe something even more efficient. I will make some research in how exactly these are implemented.

Comment: @ChirilaAlexandru: `dict` and `set` are hash tables.

Comment: @wilberforce: I'd give `blist` a better chance of landing int the stdlib. I think it's actually been considered at some point, but I don't recall the details.

Comment: @larsmans: well aren't binary search trees (search running in O(log n)) more efficient than hash tables (search running in O(n)). Since hashes are numbers, therefore easily comparable, binary search trees seem to be a more logical solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ChirilaAlexandru: hash table lookups are O(1), rather than O(n) - this is why they're so often what you want. This is sometimes balanced by the fact that choosing a good hash function can be tricky - if you have lots of collisions a lot of the benefit disappears.

Comment: @wilberforce: I got it now, thanks again for the great answer.

Comment: Or rather, hash tables in the worst case can be O(n), but with good hash functions are O(1) in the expected case. They do use more memory than a tree of the same size to help ensure the expected case actually happens, but the extra memory is also used to amortize the cost expanding the data structure as more items are added as well.

Comment: @larsmans: you might be right, although blist is based on b+ trees, I think - a bit of a different beast. Although much closer to binary trees than hash tables.

Comment: @wilberforce: yes, but B+ trees can offer the same set of operations that binary trees offer (notably Mapping + sorted iteration), just faster in most cases and using less memory.

Comment: i think sorted containers is recommended now https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers/ instead of the bintree library

Answer (score 6):

You won't find any trees in the standard library. Python heavily uses dictionary that is hash table for its internal (object, classes and modules are all based on dicts). Therefore dicts has been greatly optimized. This make the needs for search trees much smaller. Also to be efficient such trees would have been implemented in an extension type.

Comment: How do dicts make the need for search trees smaller? And what is an extension type?

Comment: dict = hash table. extension type = builtin type

Comment: To my understanding dicts don't replace search trees; they each have their own use cases

Comment: One of the main reasons one would want balanced bst instead of hashtable is the possibility to iterate all items that are less or larger than one specified, which is very efficient in case of database indexes. There's no such possibility in a hashtable without extra calculations since it's unordered