# Python, how to check object is in list?

Tags: python, object

I have an object to store data:

```
Vertex(key, children)
```

and a list to store this objects

```
vertices = []
```

im using another list

```
key_vertices = []
```

to store keys of my vertices, so i can easy access(withot looping every object), each time i need to check vertex with such key exist, like that:

```
if key not in self.key_vertices:
    # add a new key to the array
    self.key_vertices.append(key)
    # create a vertex object to store dependency information
    self.verteces.append(Vertex(key, children))
```

i think it a bit complicated, maybe someone now better way, to store multiple Vertices objects with ability easy to check and access them

Thanks

Comment: Nope. That's about as simple as your gonna get. Don't fall into the trap of thinking there's always a more cleaver way of doing something. What your doing now is perfectly fine.

Comment: @leaf Wow, you again. I would add that this way is actually pretty clever, since it makes use of magic method `__contains__`. OP did not (need to) take advantage of this, but it allows to implement a better or specific behaviour for the `in` operator.

Comment: @Rightleg That, and his code is already Pythonic. Now if he wants optimizations, then he will have to change a few things. It seems that Jean-François Fabre's covers this pretty well already.

Answer (score 4):

your example works fine, the only problem you could have is a performance issue with the `in` operator for `list` which is `O(n)`.

If you don't care about the order of the keys (which is likely), just do this:

```
self.key_vertices = set()
```

then:

```
if key not in self.key_vertices:
    # add a new key to the array
    self.key_vertices.add(key)
    # create a vertex object to store dependency information
    self.verteces.append(Vertex(key, children))
```

you'll save a lot of time in the `in` operator because `set` `in` is way faster due to key hashing.

And if you don't care about order in `self.verteces`, just do a dictionary, and in that case, you probably don't need the first `key` parameter to your `Vertex` structure.

```
self.verteces = dict()

if key not in self.verteces:
    # create a vertex object to store dependency information
    self.verteces[key] = Vertex(children)
```

Comment: ".. because set in is way faster due to order." What?

Comment: @Javier my hands wrote something my head was thinking otherwise :) fixed. thx

Comment: let's settle on "an operator eventually implemented by a C function". fixed.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to check for membership, a list is not the best choice as every object in the list will be checked.

If `key` is hashable, use a set.
If it's not hashable but is comparable, use a tree (unavailable in the standard library). Try to make it hashable.

Comment: if it's comparable, you can use `bisect`, which _is_ in the standard library.

Comment: That's useful for searching but if you insert in the middle of a list, it's an O(n) operation.

Comment: you are right about that. Given the `key` name, our only hope is to assume that it is hashable :)

Comment: apparently search trees aren't going to happen anytime soon ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857496/built-in-binary-search-tree-in-python. But such packages exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298165/pythons-standard-library-is-there-a-module-for-balanced-binary-tree

Comment: That's fine. Not everything needs to be in the standard lib.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to check if an element has already been added for `O(1)` (i.e. that you do not have to check every element in the list).

The easiest way to do that is use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). A set is an unordered *list* that allows you to check if an element exists with a constant time `O(1)`. You can think of a set like a dict with keys only but it works just like a list:

```
for value in mySet:
     print(value)

print("hello" in mySet)
```

If you need an ordered list (most of the time, you don't), your approach is pretty good but I would use a set instead:

```
self.vertece_set = set() # Init somewhere else ;)

if key not in self.vertece_set:
    # add a new key to the array
    self.vertece_set.add(key)
    # create a vertex object to store dependency information
    self.verteces.append(Vertex(key, children))
```