# How to keep a sorted list while entering data into it in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, asymptotic-complexity

I have a list of lists which need to be sorted based on the length of the lists. What I am doing now is first inserting the lists into the main list and then sort the main list giving `key=len`. This steps will take a total time of `n + nlg(n)`. Is it possible to maintain a sorted list while entering the data into the main list? Can it be done using bisect (or is there any better way) and if so will it perform better than`n + nlg(n)`?

Comment: try [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlistwithkey.html)

Comment: This [`SortedCollection`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/) reciple may be helpful (which uses `bisect`).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data structure you are using:

- [Dynamic Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)

  - Finding the right index on a sorted array is `O(log n)` using a bisect
  - Inserting is `O(n)` as you have to shift everything
  - Total `O(n)
- [Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

  - Finding the right index on a sorted linked list requires browsing the list until you get there. (`O(n)`)
  - Inserting is a simple operation, takes only `O(1)`.
  - Total `O(n)`
- [Self-balancing BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)

  - Inserting while maintaining the order and the balance is `O(log n)` *amortized*
  - There are links to implementations in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298165/pythons-standard-library-is-there-a-module-for-balanced-binary-tree)
- [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). Not exactly what you ask, but inserting into a heap is `O(log n)` or `Theta(1)` depending on the implementation you use. [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) in python is one implementation. You simple push items in your heap, and when you are done, you can get the sorted result in `O(n)`. Meanwhile you can access the root of the tree in `O(1)`, and the k smallest, sorted, in `O(k)`.