# How to convert a dict to a binary tree in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, binary-tree

```
dict = {
'a':'apple',
'b':'ball',
'c':'cat',
'd':'dog'
'e':'elepant',
'f':'fan',
'g':'goat',
}
```

If I had a dictionary like this, is it possible for me to convert it into a binary tree? i wanted to turn this into a balanced binary tree so that when the user inputs a letter to search for, it will then perform a post-order traversal to search for the letter from the tree, then, in the end, it will print the word... i'm using python 3.4...:)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Any binary tree or balanced?  By key?  Please [edit your question(https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40291004/edit) to provide some more detail of what you have tried and what you are hoping to accomplish.  **Also,** what Python version?  Py2 and Py3 may have different answers.

Comment: Near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2298165/2800918

Answer (score 0):

OK, so a short answer for a short question.

1. Don't use `dict` as the name of your variable, since that's the name of the type.  Use `words` or something instead.
2. Use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26952125/2877364).
3. Do

   ```
   tree = binary_tree(words.values())
   ```

   to get the tree of values in the form of a nested list.

   Alternatively, in Python 3, at least, you should be able to do

   ```
   tree = binary_tree( words.items() )
   ```

   to get a tree with the key and value in each list item.

**Edit** yes, link-only answers are bad. :)  The variable renaming is sufficiently important I think it's worth mentioning.