# Fastest way to exclude numbers from an array in each loop iteration

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, subset

I am not a python expert.

I am trying to implement a solution for a K-Coloring interval problem.
***Only using the python standard library, so no numpy,.***

## What i want to achieve :

So i have a **sorted** list of elements, and in each loop iteration i need to exclude multiple elements , so that in the next iteration the loop Continues to work on the **sorted** subset that resulted from the last iteration.
In each iteration i am accessing the indexes using binary search algorithm, and the list must always be sorted when worked on.

I've tried using array.pop(index) but my solution was slow and not efficient for a list of  100000 elements since it has O(n) complexity according to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity with n being number of elements in the list.

I've tried storing the inputs in a set() and work on them, however since in every iteration i have to execute binary search algorithm i can't store them because i will be needing to access elements by index for the sake of binary search, which is not possible in a set `TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable`.

Ex:

Input is a list sorted in ascending order according to the second item of each subarray.

```
arr = [[0, -1, 0], [1, 4, 0], [3, 5, 0], [0, 6, 0], [4, 7, 0], [3, 7, 0], [5, 9, 0], [6, 10, 0]]

for i in range(len(arr)) :

   x = binarysearch(arr, value) #returns an index

   while x > 0 :
      helper = x
      array.exclude(x)
      x = binarysearch(arr, arr[helper][0]) #returns an index
```

I don't want all the **arr[x]** that were excluded from the last iteration to be included in the current one.

Any ideas of thoughts would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Comment: `O(n)` sounds about the fastest you can get if you need to operate on individual elements. But your description sounds more like an `O(n^2)` problem ("... in each loop iteration i need to exclude multiple elements , so that in the next iteration ..."): loops over loops.

Comment: AFAIK there is no container in standard python that achieves both random access and deletion in less than `O(n)`. You could do this with `O(log(n))` with binary search trees, as you can implement them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not find any *naturally sorted* container in the Python standard library. So I am afraid you will have to roll your own or use a third party one. You will find some references [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2298165/3545273)