# Python - dict/set-like structures supporting unhashable keys

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, set, hashable

In Python `dict` and `set` are hash-based hence need hashable key type.

In [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) there are also hash-based [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

But C++ has variants of these structures that don't need keys to be hashable - [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). It is enough for keys to support probably just one comparison operation less `<` (also maybe equality needed `==`). Also these structures enumerate their keys in sorted order which is a very nice property unlike unordered variants.

These `std::map`/`std::set` finds/inserts key in `O(log N)` amortized time, unlike hashed structures which do this in `O(1)` time.

Although hash-based variants are faster for big enough data, they need keys to be hashable types, but in python `list`/`dict` and nested structures are unhashable hence can't be dict/set keys without extra conversion, e.g. we can convert list/dict keys to strings using `str_key = json.dumps({"x": 1, "y": [2,3]}, sort_keys = True)` or to bytes using `bytes_key = pickle.dumps({"x": 1, "y": [2,3]})` (but probably pickled variant produces same bytes only for really-really equal structures, haven't tested).

Is there any standard or popular non-standard (i.e. through `pip` modules) support for non-hash-based variant of `dict`/`set` in Python? Same like `C++`'s `std::map`/`std::set` implementations?

Probably these non-hash-based variants can be not to difficultly modeled through keeping sorted list of (key, value) pairs (sorted by key), but is there a ready-made code for this? Also just unsorted list can be used too by finding key position by `lst.index(key)`, but it has find/insert time of `O(N)` which is very-very slow for quite large data.

Just for example and fun decided to code dict solution based on sorted list (plus `bisect` module) for main dict operations, it is quite efficient (`O(log N)`) for search/get operations, but very inefficient (`O(N)`) for insertion operations (as it needs moving whole array data one place to the right at insertion points):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVXBbtswDL37K3ir1GpesgE7FE1vOw3YDwSB4dlMKtiRC0k1Ggz79oy0ZVt2kh4GTEBgiSLfI58o5fXkXxrz9Xwu6tw5cI31WGa1dj4rdeEfE6BR4h6yTBvts0w4rPeyt/PgZVo51U/aYWJgA9ud6n6rEcSiQ9tih6HARDB6DzUaEdAkPG/ATLs8LPo3a6aA4yvlCsfcv4w2w6xreHrqzGmBuhbdrG4ONHkXayaV8BlG6xcpl6XAA6X@szG4g3sQhPlpltrCv/3Qvx38uXptqHqvG0NSlvgeVKhiFfqifmmHhU/mlQdr2n8yqw8vXozqVyTzIL2MDq1ojM@JOBzcgo7k6kKWmVVySa7hGVaQm3JQaaupzvUONhuoIr4Deu3x@M901AcfUl3rieEggt@Uek5SwQ88fbe2sUJPulCWQ36KDflb7Sk5PsQoX29Pt@niUqP88b3AVz@SXo0PhJFqbqmagva/CjdXjODbqYLa4RXn@OrS7X6Atbx06ihpCx5h8tupiO7WJt9cMQOcgw4xM7ClsUNUM5QbScYwXD4LPt1TOgq3fOf2jSWBtaGuModBBjkX6qSxLkFcZ5FJwuAenRchLlx35602B8XIZXNM@tblaeoQS7EKfUtghL6B33/UxTstep9FkusVjSjHivuoI0tzV2id1eg9WrcNdPzpI7sH7IqnlNP1agntIpAeofUK7u/h26R8ua12XfL05VZTUbfRnw51NPRbm@CkQMQxculdcYksBvd6RYd@l92BaXwwq/AixfgpX/lKBo5hxfFhoQgku5s7BFsSAbEwrLoo075NpOxiRjsHjztUyLUAdcN9xkRvQhTT5YVzf8WtFjupCxdqur7hkvP5Lw)

```
class sorted_list_dict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ks, self.vs, self.n = [], [], 0
    def reserve(self, n):
        if len(self.ks) >= n:
            return
        import math
        nn = 1 << math.ceil(math.log(max(1, n)) / math.log(2))
        self.ks += [None] * (nn - len(self.ks))
        self.vs += [None] * (nn - len(self.vs))
    def insertion_index(self, k):
        import bisect
        return bisect.bisect_right(self.ks, k, 0, self.n)
    def __contains__(self, k):
        i = self.insertion_index(k)
        return i > 0 and self.ks[i - 1] == k
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        i = self.insertion_index(k)
        if i > 0 and self.ks[i - 1] == k:
            return self.vs[i - 1]
        raise KeyError(i)
    def get(self, k, default = None):
        try:
            return self.__getitem__(k)
        except KeyError:
            return default
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        i = self.insertion_index(k)
        if i > 0 and self.ks[i - 1] == k:
            self.vs[i - 1] = v
        else:
            self.reserve(self.n + 1)
            self.ks[i + 1 : self.n + 1], self.vs[i + 1 : self.n + 1], self.n = (
                self.ks[i : self.n], self.vs[i : self.n], self.n + 1,
            )
            self.ks[i], self.vs[i] = k, v
    def items(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            yield (self.ks[i], self.vs[i])

def test():
    import string, random
    random.seed(0)
    d, sld = {}, sorted_list_dict()
    for i in range(10000):
        k = string.ascii_letters[random.randrange(len(string.ascii_letters))]
        v = random.randrange(0, 10 ** 6)
        d[k], sld[k] = v, v
        assert d[k] == sld[k], (d[k], sld[k])
        assert k in sld and k + '_' not in sld, k
        assert d.get(k) == sld.get(k) and d.get(k, '__') == sld.get(k, '__')
    assert len(list(d.items())) == len(list(sld.items())), (len(list(d.items())), len(list(sld.items())))
    assert set(d.items()) == set(sld.items()), (set(d.items()), set(sld.items()))

test()
```

**Related questions**:

1. suggested by @parktomatomi about [implementations of binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298165/is-there-a-module-for-balanced-binary-tree-in-pythons-standard-library)
2. suggested by @PascalGetreuer about [implementing of hash method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909106/whats-a-correct-and-good-way-to-implement-hash)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298165/is-there-a-module-for-balanced-binary-tree-in-pythons-standard-library

Comment: Also relevant: [What's a correct and good way to implement __hash__()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909106/whats-a-correct-and-good-way-to-implement-hash)