# Searching a sorted list?

Tags: python, search, sorting

What is a Pythonic way to search or manipulate sorted [sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)?

Comment: Sequence of what? Also, what kind of search (binary, etc.)?

Comment: I believe the question is trying to be "canonical" or "generic" and so the meaning of "sequence" may be using the [Python documentation definition of a `sequence` (i.e. python 2.x "There are seven sequence types: strings, Unicode strings, lists, tuples, bytearrays, buffers, and xrange objects.")](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

Comment: Duplicate: [Binary search (bisection) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Python:

```
import bisect

def find_in_sorted_list(elem, sorted_list):
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect.bisect_left(sorted_list, elem)
    if i != len(sorted_list) and sorted_list[i] == elem:
        return i
    return -1

def in_sorted_list(elem, sorted_list):
    i = bisect.bisect_left(sorted_list, elem)
    return i != len(sorted_list) and sorted_list[i] == elem

L = ["aaa", "bcd", "hello", "world", "zzz"]
print(find_in_sorted_list("hello", L))  # 2
print(find_in_sorted_list("hellu", L))  # -1
print(in_sorted_list("hellu", L))       # False
```

Comment: @Basilevs this should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: Isn't operation `sorted_list[i]` (in `in_sorted_list`) takes O(n) defeating the purpose of `bisect`?

Answer (score 34):

[`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) is part of the standard library - is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: that doesn't explain how to search for the value in the list.

Comment: From the link you provided: "The bisect() functions are useful for finding insertion points but can be tricky or awkward to use for common searching tasks."

Comment: @MrMartin what's the difference between finding an insertion point in a sorted list, and performing a "common search task" on a sorted list?

Comment: @minseong I believe the point is that helper functions may be needed, and that search typically requires finding all matches, rather than only the first

Comment: Solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281681) answer.

Answer (score 26):

It's worth noting that there are a couple high-quality Python libraries for maintaining a sorted list which also implement fast searching: [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) and [blist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/). Using these depends of course on how often you're inserting/removing elements from the list and needing to search. Each of those modules provide a [SortedList](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) class which efficiently maintains the items in sort order.

From the documentation for SortedList:

```
L.bisect_left(value)
    Similar to the bisect module in the standard library, this returns
    an appropriate index to insert value in L. If value is already present
    in L, the insertion point will be before (to the left of) any existing
    entries.

L.bisect(value)
    Same as bisect_left.

L.bisect_right(value)
    Same as bisect_left, but if value is already present in L, the
    insertion point will be after (to the right of) any existing entries.
```

Both implementations use binary search to find the correct index of the given value. There's a [performance comparison](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) page for choosing between the two modules.

*Disclaimer*: I am the author of the sortedcontainers module.