# What happened to the self variable when it's passed into a new function?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am trying to decipher this code posted a few years back over here: [How to implement a binary search tree in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444394/implementing-binary-search-tree)

The part that I am confused about is this section:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.l_child = None
        self.r_child = None
        self.data = val

def binary_insert(root, node):
    if root is None:
        root = node
    else:
        if root.data > node.data:
            if root.l_child is None:
                root.l_child = node
            else:
                binary_insert(root.l_child, node)
        else:
            if root.r_child is None:
                root.r_child = node
            else:
                binary_insert(root.r_child, node)
```

The class and functions are then called by doing this:

```
r = Node(3)
binary_insert(r, Node(7))
binary_insert(r, Node(1))
binary_insert(r, Node(5))
```

My question is: what happened to self.data when passed into the binary_insert function? Where did node.data and root.data come from?

Comment: `self` is the instance of the `Node` class.`root` and `node` are both instances of the `Node` class as well. Think of it along the lines of.. *self=root; self.data*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses self as A way for a class to reference its own attributes. Python then implicitly fills self with your class instance once a method is called of that instance.

> what happened to self.data when passed into the binary_insert function?

Nothing. An instance of the `Node` object was passed into the `binary_searach` function. The `Node` object which was passed into the function, still has all he attributes of a `Node` object, including `self.data`.

> Where did node.data and root.data come from?

As you can see, your function takes two instances of your `Node` object as its arguments. The two node objects that are passed into the function still have all the attributes of your original `Node` class. They simply use a different alias. This can be observed directly by printing out the type of the `root` and `node` parameters:

At the begining of your function we can print the types of `root` and `node`:

```
def binary_insert(root, node):
    print("The type of root is:", type(root))
    print("The type of node is:", type(node))
    ...
```

Which when called outputs:

```
The type of root is: <class 'Node'>
The type of node is: <class 'Node'>
The type of root is: <class 'Node'>
The type of node is: <class 'Node'>
The type of root is: <class 'Node'>
The type of node is: <class 'Node'>
The type of root is: <class 'Node'>
The type of node is: <class 'Node'>
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful...I think I get most of it, but in the past, I would use self.data as its own variable. So what happens if I use self.data in the code?

Comment: @jessibird What code are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

These are exactly what happened to `self.data`. `root.data` accesses the `data` property of `root`, which is an instance of the `Node` class.