# Inserting a value in a ordered sequence in O(ln n)

Tags: python, performance, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure (delimited by % in this exemple) in python, which can efficiently (O(ln n) or better...) perform insertion in a ordered sequence:

```
insert ( 6, % 3, 4, 9 %) ->  % 3, 4, 6, 9 %
```

For `list` and `np.ndarray` it's O(n).  `dict` or `set` are unordered.

Is there a builtin (or not)  way to do that ?

Comment: Have you looked into ordered dict?

Comment: It seems it keeps inserting order, not value order.

Comment: You can trade O(1) indexing for O(log n) indexing to get O(log n) insertion with a binary search tree like a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), or O(1) indexing for O(n) indexing in a linked list to get O(1) insertion relative to a node you have. More context, please? (i.e. what are you using this data structure for?)

Comment: See [Time Complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## List ?

[`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) could help you, at least when looking for the position where the element should be inserted (`O(log n)`) :

```
import bisect
l = [3, 4, 9]
bisect.insort_left(l , 6)
print(l)
# [3, 4, 6, 9]
```

From the documentation, though :

> Keep in mind that the O(log n) search is dominated by the slow O(n)
>   insertion step.

So list is indeed a problem, not the search itself. Python [TimeComplexity's table](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) doesn't show any alternative with O(log n) insertion.

## Binary Search Tree

From this [table](http://bigocheatsheet.com/), it looks like "Binary Search Tree" has O(log n) for Access, Search and Insertion. There are other structures that fit the bill as well, but this might be the most well-known.

This [answer (Implementing binary search tree)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5444796/6419007) should help you. As an example :

```
r = Node(3)
binary_insert(r, Node(9))
binary_insert(r, Node(4))
binary_insert(r, Node(6))

in_order_print(r)
# 3
# 4
# 6
# 9
```

Comment: Unfortunately ,   `insort_left`  doc says : Keep in mind that the O(log n) search is dominated by the slow O(n) insertion step.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple data structures that can do what you want,  but I don't think there is a built in version of any of them. You can use a [skip list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) or a self balancing binary search ree (e.g. [red-black](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) tree, [AVL tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)). There are side packages that contain those structures. For instance [bintrees](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/2.0.1) has implementations for avl and red black trees.

Comment: Thanks for your accurate answer. I will try all the trees of the forest to find the best for me.