# Build binary search tree using dictionary in Python

Tags: python, recursion, parameter-passing, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to build a BST (binary search tree) with dict in python. I do not understand why my code is not adding nodes to the BST. I saw a similar post here:
[How to implement a binary search tree in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444394/how-to-implement-a-binary-search-tree-in-python)
which looks the same as my code except declaring a node class, but I would like to know why my dict implementation fails (and hopefully improve my understanding of parameter passing with recursion in python).

```
keys = [10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18]
start = {'key': keys[-1], 'val': 1, 'left': None, 'right': None}
def binarySearch(root, node):
# compare keys and insert node into right place
    if not root:
        root = node
    elif node['key'] < root['key']:
        binarySearch(root['left'], node)
    else:
        binarySearch(root['right'], node)

# Now let's test our function and build a BST
while keys:
    key = keys.pop()
    node = {'key': key, 'val': 1, 'left': None, 'right': None}
    binarySearch(start, node)
print(start) # unchanged, hence my confusion. Thx for your time!
```

===========================================

Edit: here is the code that would make it work!

```
def binarySearch(root, node):
# compare keys and insert node into right place
    if not root:
        root = node
    elif node['key'] < root['key']:
        if not root['left']: root['left'] = node
        else: binarySearch(root['left'], node)
    else:
        if not root['right']: root['right'] = node
        else: binarySearch(root['right'], node)
```

Here is what I think that is happening under the hood (why one version is able to add to BST but the other one is not):

In the original version, we will reach a recursion call where `root` still points to None inside the BST, but then `root = node` make `root` points to `node` which has absolutely no connection with `start`, i.e. the BST itself. Then local variables are deleted and no changes are made.

In the modified version, we will avoid this since when we add the node by e.g. `root['left'] = node`. Here `root` is still pointing to the original BST and thus we are modifying the key-val pair in the original BST instead of having `root` point to something totally outside the BST.

Comment: `root = node` defines a new _local variable_ called `root`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: The accepted answer of the linked question deals with left or right being None instead of recursing.

Comment: @ForceBru inside the function root is the first argument passed to the function, independent of the root outside. I've edited the code to clear any confusion.

Comment: @quamrana they were able to insert the node to the root so I thought I could do the same with dict, but I'm not sure why it fails..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's run through your code as though we were the python interpreter.

Lets start at the first call: `binarySearch(start, node)`

Here `start` is the `dict` defined at the top of your script and `node` is another `dict` (which curiously has the same value).

Lets jump inside the call and we find ourselves at: `if not root:` where `root` refers to `start` above and so is `truthy` so fails this `if`.

Next we find ourselves at: `elif node['key'] < root['key']:` which in this case is not `True`.

Next we pass into the `else:` and we are at: `binarySearch(root['right'], node)`.

Just before we jump into the first recursive call, lets review what the parameters to the call are: `root['right']` from `start` has the value `None` and `node` is still the same `dict` which we want to insert somewhere. So, onto the recursive call.

Again we find ourselves at: `if not root:`

However this time `root` just refers to the first parameter of the first recursive call and we can see from the above review of the parameters that `root` refers to `None`.

Now `None` is considered `falsy` and so this time the `if` succeeds and we are on to the next line.

Now we are at `root = node`.

This is an assignment in python. What this means is that python will use the variable `root` to stop referring to `None` and to refer to whatever `node` currently refers to, which is the `dict` which was created in the `while` loop. So `root` (which is just a parameter, but you can think of as a local variable now) refers to a `dict`.

Now what happens is that we are at the end of the first recursive call and this function ends. Whenever a function ends, all the local variables are destroyed. That is `root` and `node` are destroyed. That is just these variables and not what they refer to.

Now we return to just after the first call site i.e. just after `binarySearch(root['right'], node)`

We can see here that the parameters: `root['right'], node` still refer to whatever they were referring to before. This is why your `start` is unchanged and why your program should deal with `left` and `right` now instead of recursing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation! May I ask how to modify the code so that one could successfully insert the node into the ```start``` outside the function?

Comment: Well, as I commented before, its there in the accepted answer of the linked question.

Comment: Right... I did make it work and added it to the post. But if I understood your answer correctly when it passes ```root['left']``` into the recursive call, it will still assign ```root``` to point to ```root['left']``` as a local variable to be destroyed by the end of that recursion call. So we are never going to be able to make changes beyond first recursion?

Comment: I'm referring to the part 'Now what happens is that we are at the end of the first recursive call and this function ends. Whenever a function ends, all the local variables are destroyed. That is root and node are destroyed. That is just these variables and not what they refer to.'

Comment: Your `while keys:` loop (which should be `for key in keys:` btw) keeps feeding new `node`s into `binarySearch()` (which should be `binaryInsert()` btw) so at some point both `left` and `right` of `start` will have their own `node`s. Then at the next call there will be an `else: binarySearch(...)` which passes one of the previously added `node`s in, which becomes `root` and then there is the possibility of that `node` being modified, just as `start` was.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand what you mean now and I've added that to the post (I'd appreciate it if you could just confirm if my logic is right). And yeah I would use for loop except in the script above I'm poping the keys, so while loop will terminate and do the same job.

Answer (score -1):

```
#Creted by The Misunderstood Genius
def add_root(e,key):
    ''''
     e is node's name
    key is the node's key search
    '''
    bst=dict()
    bst[e]={'key':key,'P':None,'L':None,'R':None}
    return bst
def root(tree):
   for k,v in tree.items():
       if v['P'] == None:
           return k





def insert(tree, node, key):
    tree[node]={'key':key,'P':None,'L':None,'R':None}
    y =None
    x = root(tree)
    node_key = tree[node]['key']
    while x is not None:
        y=x
        node_root=tree['R']['key']
        if node_key < node_root:
            x=tree[x]['L']
        else:
            x=tree[x]['R']
    tree[node]['P']=y
    if y is not None and node_key< tree[y]['key']:
        tree[y]['L']=node
    else:
        tree[y]['R']=node

    return  tree


def print_all(tree):
   for k,v in tree.items():
       print(k,v)
       print()
'''
Give a root node and key search target 
Returns the name of the node with associated key 
Else None
'''
def tree_search(tree,root, target):
    if root ==None:
        print(" key with node associate not found")
        return root
    if tree[root]['key'] == target:
        return  root
    if target < tree[root]['key']:
        return tree_search(tree,tree[root]['L'],target)
    else:
        return  tree_search(tree,tree[root]['R'],target)

def tree_iterative_search(tree,root,target):


    while root is not  None and tree[root]['key']!=target:

        if target < tree[root]['key']:
            root=tree[root]['L']


        else:
            root=tree[root]['R']


    return root

def minimum(tree,root):
    while tree[root]['L'] is not None:
        root=tree[root]['L']
    return tree[root]['key']






bst=add_root('R',20)

bst=insert(bst,'M',10)
bst=insert(bst,'B',8)
bst=insert(bst,'C',24)
bst=insert(bst,'D',22)
bst=insert(bst,'E',25)
bst=insert(bst,'G',25)
print_all(bst)
print(tree_search(bst,'R',25))
x=tree_iterative_search(bst,'R',25)
print(x)
#print(minimum(bst,'R'))
```