# Create sorted list while creation

Tags: python, list, data-structures

Can we create sorted list while creation of list itself?

Or

Is there any other data structure that can place values in sorted order, at creation time?

```
list = []
list.append("cde")
list.append("abc")
list.append("xyz")  # append element in sorted order itself
```

I am familiar with

```
list.sort()  #or
list = sorted(list)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527630/is-there-a-standard-python-data-structure-that-keeps-thing-in-sorted-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to perform ordered insertions within a sequence.

> `bisect.bisect_left`(*a, x, lo=0, hi=len(a)*)
>
> Locate the insertion point for *x* in *a* to maintain sorted order. [...] The return value is suitable for use as the first parameter to `list.insert()` assuming that *a* is already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OrderedDict` to create ordered dictionaries.
You can import `OrderedDict` from here `from collections import OrderedDict`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `heapq` methods

```
>>> list = []
>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.heappush(list, "cde")
>>> heapq.heappush(list, "abc")
>>> heapq.heappush(list, "xyz")
>>> heapq.nsmallest(3, list)
['abc', 'cde', 'xyz']
```

It's not actually ordered, but you could perform ordered operations you need

Answer (score 0):

I found this is useful,

```
class SList(list):
    def append(self, data):
        super(SList, self).append(data)
        super(SList, self).sort()


slist = SList()
slist.append("cde")
slist.append("abc")
slist.append("xyz")
print slist
```

In same way we can override other methods also to keep list state sorted