# How to find an index at which a new item can be inserted into sorted list and keep it sorted?

Tags: python, sortedlist

```
a = 132

b = [0, 10, 30, 60, 100, 150, 210, 280, 340, 480, 530]
```

I want to know that `a` should be in the 6th position in ordered list `b`.

What's the most pythonic way to do so?

Comment: `a` will actually be in the 6th position in `b`, not the 4th. And as @madjar noted, used the `bisect` module.  `bisect.bisect(b, a)` to get the position (or `bisect_[left|right]`) and for insertion `bisect.insort(b, a)` or `insort[left|right]`.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109804/does-python-have-a-sorted-list

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [bisect](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/bisect.html). It's not the most beautiful API, but it's exactly what you need.

You'll want to use `bisect.bisect`, which returns exactly what you want.

Comment: Why is it "not the most beautiful API"?

Answer (score 48):

[`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) is a module in the Python Standard Library that is perfect for this task. The function `bisect` in the module `bisect` will give you the index of the insertion point for the value.

Let me give a code example for `bisect`

```
from bisect import bisect
a = 132
b = [0, 10, 30, 60, 100, 150, 210, 280, 340, 480, 530]
print(bisect(b, a))
```

The result will be `5` because the list is 0-based, so in fact it is the 6th position.

What you can do know is to use the result for an `insert`.

```
index = bisect(b, a)
b.insert(index, a)
```

or without the intermediate variable

```
b.insert(bisect(b, a), a)
```

Now `b` will be `[0, 10, 30, 60, 100, 132, 150, 210, 280, 340, 480, 530]`.

Comment: what if a is an object or dictionary and b is a sorted list of objects or dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

There is further concern with edge cases. For example, suppose you want to select the elements in the aforementioned `b` in the range of `(a, c)` and you pick them out using

```
b[idx_a:idx_c]
```

then you need to think about the case where `a, c` are actually elements of `b`. Note that

```
bisect.bisect(b, 10)
bisect.bisect(b, 11)
```

would both give index 2. Thus if `a=10` we need to lower the index by 1. Fortunately, there is a function `bisect.bisect_left` which does exactly this, i.e., in our example

```
bisect.bisect_left(b, 10)
```

gives 1.

Overall, the left index should be computed using `bisect.bisect_left()` and the right index `bisect.bisect_right()` (which is the same as `bisect.bisect()`).