# What is the cleanest way to search a word into a list of strings?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, search

I have a list like this:

```
['abaissement\t[n.m] - recessione [n]\n', 'abaisser\t[vblex] - abbassare [vblex]\n', 'abandon\t[n] - abbandono [n]\n']
```

The first word of each item is sorted alphabetically and this is the one I want to find. By find I hear return the index of the word.

Should I reorganize my list, or is there an clean and quick (because the list has 6000 items) way to do this?

Comment: As well as [Most pythonic way to find number index in a sorted list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11290767)

Comment: It works if I search only the first word, but when I do this : print bisect(b, 'recessione') I have : 3, why?