# Improve speed for list concatenation?

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

I have a list called L inside a loop that must iterate though millions of lines. The salient features are:

```
for line in lines:
    L = ['a', 'list', 'with', 'lots', 'of', 'items']
    L[3] = 'prefix_text_to_item3' + L[3]
    Do more stuff with L...
```

Is there a better approach to adding text to a list item that would speed up my code. Can .join be used? Thanks.

Comment: The example makes it look like string concatenation rather than list concatenation. Can you fix it to be more like the true problem, or fix the description?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you do with `line`. Do you want to concatenate lists or strings ?

Comment: Sorry my example was unclear. Basically, I am trying to prefix a string to the beginning of a list item. Take a string 'dog' and prefix onto a list item L[2]. In my example, this would produce the list item 'dogwith'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a performance oriented code, it is not a good idea to add 2 strings together, it is preferable to use a `"".join(_items2join_)` instead. (I found some benchmarks there : http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/)

Comment: Why would that be? I'd think they would be the same, unless you're joining more than 2 strings.

Comment: You are wrong. `''.join()` will be much slower then concatenation while working with two strings. See http://pastebin.com/6jWmpRs8

Comment: I was confused by the wording of your answer - first you say "add 2 strings" then you say "items2join" which made me think you were comparing two ways of appending 2 strings. The larger point you were trying to make is not clear.

Comment: That source (http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) uses 20k and 500k for its benchmarks. For two strings, there's absolutely zero advantage. For a few (more than two) strings, there's probably no reason to. Only for really large strings you should avoid repeated concatenation.

Comment: Well, the conclusion of this (and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376461/string-concatenation-vs-string-substitution-in-python) is that you should try the different solutions and benchmark them to find the most efficient solution in your case. :-).

Answer (score 1):

Since accessing an element in a python list is O(1), and appending a list to another is O(1) (which is probably the time complexity of concatenating strings in python), The code you have provided is running as fast as it can as far as I can tell. :) You probably can't afford to do this, but when I need speed I go to C++ or some other compiled language when I need to process that much information. Things run much quicker. For time complexity of list operations in python, you may consult this web site: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity and here: [What is the runtime complexity of python list functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005590/what-is-the-runtime-complexity-of-python-list-functions)

Comment: 1. Appending a list to another is not O(1)... O(1) is for appending a single item.  List concat should be equivalent to set slice - O(k+n).  2. He's not concatenating lists, he's concatenating strings. (prefix + l[i])

Answer (score 1):

Don't actually create list objects.

Use generator functions and generator expressions.

```
def appender( some_list, some_text ):
    for item in some_list:
        yield item + some_text
```

This `appender` function does not actually create a new list.  It avoids some of the memory management overheads associated with creating a new list.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better approach depending on what you are doing with list L.

For instance, if you are printing it, something like this may be faster.

print "{0} {1} {2} {3}{4} {5}".format(L[0], L[1], L[2], 'prefix_text_to_item3', L[3], L[4])

What happens to L later in the program?