# What is the time compplexity of this?

Tags: time, complexity-theory

i want to known the time complexity of this code
python3 code :

```
def twoStacks(maxSum, a, b):
    # Write your code here
    sum_all=0
    times=-1
    while sum_all<maxSum:
        if a[0]<b[0] and len(a)>0 and len(b)>0 or len(a)>0 and len(b)==0:
            poped_a=a.pop(0)
            sum_all=sum_all+poped_a
            times=times+1
        elif a[0]>b[0] and len(a)>0 and len(b)>0 or len(b)>0 and len(a)==0:
            poped_b=b.pop(0)
            sum_all=sum_all+poped_b
            times=times+1
    return times
```

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question about calculating the time complexity? Is it that you  can't figure out the number of times the `while` loop executes? Or you don't know the complexity of the `if/elif` statement?

Comment: its about the while loop as well as the inbuilt functions complexity like pop() and len()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the runtime complexity of python list functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005590/what-is-the-runtime-complexity-of-python-list-functions)

Comment: no, i need exact time complexity of  this code

Comment: Please be specific what your question is. Is it that you cannot calculate how many iterations are run? What have you calculated so far?